# How to get open window's ID and then resize that open window

Tags: c#, resize

I would like to resize any open window by coding. I checked all the questions here, there is no answer for me. A possible scenario can be like this.

I clicked on the Computer Icon on the desktop. Window is opened. Then I clicked on the Documents Icon on the desktop. Window is opened. Now, there are 2 open windows. I will click on one of them and that window will be topmost. ( I dont know how to get this Window's ID ) Then there is a menu which I already created with some sizes. I will click on one of them and the window will be resized. If I click on other open window, it will be topmost and then I will do the same operations for it.

If you help me with some sample code, that will be perfect since I'm new on this topic.

The most importing thing is that this windows will not be created by me.It will be any window which is already done by windows.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't a WPF question. I don't know a lot about windows API calls, however Windows has an executable called `explorer.exe`, which manages desktop UI such as window management.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should start from using [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) and [GetActiveWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetActiveWindow.html) functions using P/Invoke. And to set size and position of found window use [SetWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html) function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would say that these are so advanced for me :S

Comment: I'm afraid that you won't find other ways to achieve that.